# No module named string error at werkzeug

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, devops, werkzeug

When I'm trying to deploy my flask app with virtualenv on my vds. I'm getting the following errors. Firstly let me describe what steps I use when I'm deploying it.

Firstly I choose python3 interpreter with alias.

```
alias python3=/home/web/bin/python3.5
```

Then I go app folder and deploy with :

```
python3 app.py
```

But unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, Response, json
  File "/home/web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/home/web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "/home/web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 67, in <module>
    from werkzeug._internal import _get_environ
  File "/home/web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/_internal.py", line 12, in <module>
    import string
ImportError: No module named 'string'
```

The weird things here are when I do the same steps on another server it's deploying without problem.
And also maybe it's a different question but; on my local computer when I activate virtualenv the python3 interpreter changes automatically. But on the remote server I have to do alias command thing.

My sys.path on the remote server is:

```
['', '/home/web/lib/python35.zip', '/home/web/lib/python3.5', '/home/web/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/home/web/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/home/web/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

By the way I'm using CentOS on my remote server, other servers I wrote about were Ubuntu.

Comment: `string` should be in your stdlib. Either you've got a broken `sys.path` somehow (try `print(sys.path)` in your code before importing the Flask stuff), or you've got a broken stdlib and need to reinstall.

Comment: @celnmeh Edit that into the question, don't put it in a comment.